# Firemonkey TCanvas draw transformed TBitmap

Tags: bitmap, transform, firemonkey

I'd like to draw a TBitmap with new edge points over Canvas. Is there a efficient way to do this, preferably with something which is built-into Firemonkey.

The only method I would know of is to use **TPerspectiveTransformEffect** but i want to avoid this and use the Canvas instead. It doesnt matter if i transform the TBitmap before drawing or draw it with some Firmeonkey feature transformed.

I'd like to set TopLeft, TopRight, BottomLeft and BottomRight origin.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you look into DrawBitmap? Simply paint your bitmap like this: Canvas.DrawBitmap(MyTBitmap, MySourceRect, MyDestinationRect, 1); (http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/FMX.Graphics.TCanvas.DrawBitmap)

Comment: Thats not what im looking for... I want to set **all** the TopLeft, TopRight, BottomLeft and BottomRight, so that i can draw a bitmap in another perspective way. Thanks anyways! :)

Comment: You can specify any destination rect, which will stretch the source rect to fit.